# Problem with DB after cloning project from repo // PHP laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with my Laravel project. After cloning the repo from git I did

```
npm install
composer install
```

`php artisan migrate` I have an error:

> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `languages` where `status` =
>   1)
>
> In Connector.php line 70:
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

I've added few changes to `.env` file only

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:q/o7QZeznstW1iBW65t8F7usVPI1oA9osHGaCa6uONU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=newDB
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I am using **mamp** on **mac** os for my web environment.

**Error Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: can u run this command `php artisan config:clear` ?

Comment: Yes but I have the same error message when I run php artisan config:clear

Comment: What do you get when you run ` $ mysql -u root --host=localhost --port=8889 newDB -p` and typed in `root` as the password? Have you created the `newDB` table and the `root` user with `root` password?

Comment: I prefer the unix socket provided by mamp's mysql installation

Comment: @DelenaMalan when I run your code I have "Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) " and yes this is new empty db with standard namp user credentials (user: root, pass: root) When I am connecting to db via browser localhost:8889 so everything is good and I can connect

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your `.env` file

`DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

I use MAMP too and always need this inside my `.env` files

Comment: Thanks :) I add your code to .env but still not working :(

Comment: Make sure you clear your cache after to be sure. Try leaving the password blank to when using root to see if that works

Comment: Hi, thanks. I run ' php artisan config:cache ' every time when I update .env

Answer (score 1):

Open the `.env` file and edit it.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:q/o7QZeznstW1iBW65t8F7usVPI1oA9osHGaCa6uONU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=            // Your Database Name
DB_USERNAME=           // Yout Database Username
DB_PASSWORD=          // Your Database Password
```

NOTE: If no password is set on the database, clear it `DB_PASSWORD`

This error basically comes from the after changes in the .env file:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

After completion of `.env` edit, must be clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: I had these fields filled with my mamp db information (Check printscreen). Still not working. I have this error when I type all php artisan command :(

Comment: Hello @DarekP The solution to the error is my answer, if you still have an error then Sorry I'm not familiar with Mac OS